# Easiest way to batch convert TXT to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk

Our company is switching to a new system which only outputs reports as TXT or DOC files. I am looking to convert these to PDF so I can display them more easily through the web portal.

I use PDFTK currently to produce PDFs from forms on our intranet but I can't see this working for documents that won't always be a standard size. Depending on who the report is for it may be 1 page or 20.

We also use [Batch & Print](http://www.traction-software.co.uk/batchprint/) for various things and I tried having it print to a PDF file but so far it will only store the files on the root of C:\ since it doesn't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question on another SE site with some vendor options:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/net-library-to-convert-microsoft-office-docs-to-pdf

If you are looking for another vendor solution there's:

https://www.wordtopdf.com/

If you were looking to write your own solution, could you provide more detail as to the technology you'd like to use or are currently using? Are you planning to have Office installed on the machine that would handle the conversion? Will this happen on the fly when documents are requested or are you looking to run the documents through in batches?

Comment: We don't use .NET so I'm not sure those would work well for what we need. I would prefer to either write my own or possible use some other software. All of our servers are windows based. If we need to have office installed on the machine doing the conversion that would not be an issue. I believe this will best be managed as a batch since the documents will be produced at night as a batch as well.